# Object Not Defined with Knockout Data Mapping Plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use the mapping plugin to make children objects' properties observable.  I have the following:

```
// setData defined here

var mapping = {

    create: function(options) {
        //customize at the root level.  
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(function () {
            debugger;
            return this.cards().length;  // cards not defined - "this" is Window for some reason
        });

        innerModel.deleteCard = function (card) {
            // Pending UI
            // call API here
            // On success, complete
            this.cards.remove(card);
        }.bind(this);

        innerModel.addCard = function () {
            //debugger;
            // Pending UI
            // Call API here
            // On success, complete
            this.cards.push(dummyCard);
            //this.cardToAdd("");
        }.bind(this);

        return innerModel;
    }
};

var SetViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(setData, mapping);

ko.applyBindings(SetViewModel);
```

When I run this in chrome debugger, I get "Object [Object global] has no method cards".  Cards *should* be an observable array.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(function () {
            debugger;
            return this.cards().length;  // cards not defined - "this" is Window for some reason
        });
```

`this` is inside the anonymous function you're creating and is therefore bound to the global object.  if you want to reference innermodel you'll have to do so directly, or bind innermodel to the function.

```
innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(function () {
            return innerModel.cards().length; 
        });
```

or

```
var computedFunction = function () {
            return this.cards().length; 
        };
innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(computedFunction.apply(innerModel));
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that helped a lot.